# How do I implement an Access Database to Blue J (Java) without using an SQL server?

Tags: java, database, ms-access, bluej

I want to be able to import the data in the database into blue J and run queries and then display the results to the user. However, I want to do this without the use of an ODBC DSN and an SQL server. I just want to be able to search the database using SQL directly. Is there a way I can do this? I have imported the SQL library, but am not sure how to use this to link to the database I have made. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to access a relational database in Java is by using JDBC. There is a lot of tutorials.

for exemple (for a MySQL DB):

```
    public Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        // could be an IP address, including localhost instead of an URL
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://my-url.com:3306/my_database", "user", "password");
    }

    public void test() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        try(Connection c = getConnection()) {
            try (PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("SELECT id, name FROM person WHERE email = ?")) {
                ps.setString(1, "john.doe@mail.com");
                try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        Integer id = rs.getInt("id");
                        String name = rs.getString("name");
                        System.out.println(id + " " + name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The jar of the Driver has to be in the class path

---

Edit

[UcanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) is JDBC Driver for MS-Access